# JSP conditional expression in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Please take a look at this javascript code inside  a GSP(similar to JSP):

```
var json =JSON.parse("${savedkpiz.get(0).kpi.replace("\"","\\\"")}")
```

**savedkpiz(list object)** object is sometimes have no element so access at 0 will throw NPE, how can i prevent this code from executing?? JavaScript if else seems not working

```
var json =JSON.parse("${if(savedkpiz.size()>0) ? savedkpiz.get(0).kpi.replace("\"","\\\""):""}")
```

above code too not working?? how can i put condition on this and at the same time if true then populate json variable.

Please help guyz, thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot call methods (other than getters) on elements accessed with `${}`.

Comment: Is the first code working? I don't think so, since you are delimiting the strings with double quotes even inside the string itself, making it end and restart more than once. You should escape the double quotes inside the main string or use single quotes(if allowed).

Comment: @LightStyle first code is working fine!!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what else i can do??

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis where can i learn more about ${} ????

Comment: In our wiki for it : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your logic and achieve what you want by using JSTL's `<c:if>` tag and doing the string substitution in JavaScript instead.

```
var jsonStr = "";

<c:if test="${not empty savedkpiz}">
    jsonStr = "${savedkpiz[0]}".replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
</c:if>

var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to just check for `${not empty savedkpiz}`.

Comment: @user1983983, that is so much better. Thanks for sharing.